# How can I get certain values to show in a second drop-down based on the value of the first drop-down?

Tags: ms-access, inheritance

I have an access form with two drop-down lists: `Investigation` and `Activity`.

There are 12 investigations and each one has three activities linked to it.

I have created a back end system with two tables (`investigations` and `activities`) that contain the values for each respective drop-down list and which are linked to the front end where the users interact with the system via forms.

What I want to happen is when a user selects `Investigation 1` from the `investigations` drop-down list, the `activities` drop-down list displays activities 1, 2 and 3.  Similarly, when a user selects `Investigation 8`, then I want the `activities` drop-down list to display activities 22, 23 and 24, and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: search for cascading dropdown/combobox in ms access, you will find plenty!

Answer (score 0):

Search for `cascading dropdown` or `dependent dropdown`. Here is a link to get you started.

[Dependent dropdown list box](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/comboboxlist/access_dependent_dropdown_list.htm)